# Does Photos upload have builtin throttling?

Tags: icloud, photos, sharing

I have Photos creating a shared album.  It seems to upload five or six photos, wait ten to fifteen minutes, then upload some more.

Judging by web search results, this is new behavior (or limited to my situation).  Many hits of people wanting to know how to slow it down; none (in the first page of results) complaining that it **is** slow.

Has Apple recently done something to limit the Photos bandwidth?

A [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241842/icloud-photo-sharing-extremely-slow) **seemed** to have an answer.  The difference is that they were sharing photos already uploaded, while I was sharing new ones.

But if Apple is merely resizing them **locally**, and then uploading, the speed is still unexplained.  GraphicConverter resizes an image in one or two seconds, not ten/twenty/thirty.  And an upload of a 2048-pixel wide photo should be fast as well.  (After all, images taken by an iPhone appear on other devices as fast as I can open the device.)

Comment: There are 81 images totaling 112MB.  After more than two hours, 51 images have uploaded.

Comment: What platform is photos running on? iOS or macOS and what version of the app and the os? Shared albums have to be copied to a global CDN so they can take longer than your photo album sync up but let’s get the details fixed before I speculate too much on an answer.

Comment: @bmike: According to another Q/A, much of the slowness (MacOS) is due to resizing (I edited while you were commenting).  But that is either wrong or incompetent coding, as GraphicConverter can do such a resize in a second.